# How to parse geocoding geoApi (formattedAddress) one line address format into multiple components?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
public String[] splitAddress(String address) {

    String[] arrOfStr = address.split(",", 3);
    if (!(address.substring(address.length() - 6).equalsIgnoreCase("sweden"))) {

        return new String[]{arrOfStr[0], arrOfStr[1], null};
    }

    if (arrOfStr.length == 2) {
        return new String[]{null, arrOfStr[0], arrOfStr[1]};
    }

    if (arrOfStr.length == 1) {
        return new String[]{null, arrOfStr[0], null};
    }


    return arrOfStr;
}


static String[] splitString(String str)
{
    StringBuilder alpha = new StringBuilder(),
    StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
            num.append(str.charAt(i));
        else if(Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i)))
            alpha.append(str.charAt(i));

    }
    return new String[]{alpha.toString(), num.toString()};
}
```

```
String str = "vårbergvägrn 6,145 67 Norsborg,Sweden";

ParseAddress parseAddress = new ParseAddress(); // object of the class

System.out.println("Street  : " + parseAddress.splitAddress(str)[0]);
System.out.println("PostalCode  : " + ParseAddress.splitString(parseAddress.splitAddress(str)[1])[1]);
System.out.println("City  : " +  ParseAddress.splitString(parseAddress.splitAddress(str)[1])[0]);
System.out.println("Country  : " + parseAddress.splitAddress(str)[2]);
```

```
resuts
Street  : vårbergvägrn 6
PostalCode  : 14567
City  : Norsborg
Country  : Sweden
```

I'm trying to parse the `geocoding` google Api (formattedAdress) one line component(adress) in to diffrent fields i.e. street, postalcode , city and country (which is our Sweden adress format and we need it for out application).

As I am on my practical job and student of `java`, my superviser commented on the code that it is very hard coded and not clean. I am here to get help. How may I make my code flexible , clean and not hard coded. if any of you  share a new method/ piece of code , it will be appreciated.

To be clear: I am not stuck with my code, I just need it organized a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Split on comma (,) delimiters for any delimiter/space configuration:

```
String[] parts = address.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

This will provide you with a String[] array of the Street, PostCode & City, and the Country;

Place the Street portion into a String variable:

```
String street = parts[0];
```

The Postal Code and City are blended together in the initial parsing now held within `parts[1]`. These two can be easily separated (parsed further) by utilizing the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method and a couple small [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex), for example, to get the **Postal Code** from `parts[1]` we can use:

```
String postalCode = parts[1].replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

The `"\\D"` expression removes all non-numerical characters from the string it is played upon. This will then ultimately leave `postalCode` variable holding `14567`.

The same idea can be played again on `parts[1]` to get the **City** name, we just use a different regex, for example:

```
String city = parts[1].replaceAll("\\d+ ", "");
```

The `"\\d+ "` expression removes all numerical digits (`\\d+`) and whitespaces (note the whitespace in the expression) from the string it is played upon. This will then ultimately leave the `city` variable holding `Norsborg`.

Country is simply the final element within the array created from the initial split:

```
String country = parts[2];
```

The whole thing could look something like this:

```
String address = "vårbergvägrn 6,145 67 Norsborg,Sweden";

String[] parts = address.split("\\s*,\\s*");
String street = parts[0];
String postalCode = parts[1].replaceAll("\\D", "");
String city = parts[1].replaceAll("\\d+ ", "");
String country = parts[2];
    
System.out.println("Street:    " + street);
System.out.println("Post Code: " + postalCode);
System.out.println("City:      " + city);
System.out.println("Country:   " + country);
```

If run, the console window would display:

```
Street:    vårbergvägrn 6
Post Code: 14567
City:      Norsborg
Country:   Sweden
```